# What changed in the driver signature requirements for Windows 8?

Tags: c++, installation, driver, digital-signature, windows-8

I've got a passthrough [NDIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Driver_Interface_Specification) intermediate driver, consisting of two .inf files (one standard and one miniport) and a .sys file. Because of the Windows 7 driver signing requirements, I had to get a code-signing certificate and sign the .sys file in order for the driver to install on a 64-bit system. This works fine, and I have many successful Windows 7 installs.

However, the same installer fails on the Windows 8 Consumer Preview (64-bit). If I boot with Windows Signature Enforcement turned off, it installs correctly, so it's definitely a signature issue. What new requirements were added between Windows 7 & Windows 8 that I need to follow in order to get my driver to install?

Comment: FWIW: I used to modify my graphics driver's .inf files to make them work with my system. (The versions that work out of the box are from the OEM, and hence older.) It worked fine on Windows XP and Windows 7, both 32-bit and 64-bit, but Windows 8 64-bit tells me that I can't install it due to tampering, even though I've turned off signature enforcement. :( I have no idea what they did, but it's pretty darn annoying...

Comment: FWIW: I had to create a .cat file for my .inf and then test sign the .cat file to get it to install on Windows 8 Customer Preview X64. That leads me to believe that the only way to deploy it for release would require a code signing cert from a Certificate Authority. This .inf is used to install a USB CDC device that uses Microsoft's usbser.sys driver.

Comment: If there any official word from Microsoft on whether all INF files need to be signed in the final release of Windows 8?  Before I go through the trouble of signing all our drivers I would like to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regenerate your cat file(s) so that they comply with the signing requirements for the new Window OS.

For example, in my build script I had to add `8_X86,8_X64` to my `inf2cat` command:

```
inf2cat /driver:"%CD%" /os:XP_X86,XP_X64,Vista_X86,Vista_X64,7_X86,7_X64,8_X86,8_X64
```

---

For Windows 8.1, you will need the `inf2cat` included in Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8.1 and depending on your target(s) add `6_3_X64`, `6_3_X86`, or `6_3_ARM` to the /os:WindowsVersionList.

Reference, *[Inf2Cat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

Comment: I've been getting away without a cat file at all, but I'll try this.

Comment: This solved the problem, although it prompts the user whether they want to install the driver. That's not ideal, but it's much better than not installing.

Comment: @jeffm: make sure you also sign your cat file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The cat files and the driver are signed. I'm thinking maybe I need to add the certificate to the local store first.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I use `makecat` to generate the .cat file and I never included the "<HASH>" at the beginning of the .cdf file lines that list the filenames. That worked with Windows 7, but no longer with Windows 8.

See the `makecat` website here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4

I had a .cdf file like this:

```
[CatalogHeader]
Name=xxx.cat
[CatalogFiles]
xxx.sys=xxx.sys
```

This worked with Windows 7, but not with Windows 8.

The following works with Windows 8 as well, plus it gives a nicer dialog when installing, even under Windows 7:

```
[CatalogHeader]
Name=xxx.cat
[CatalogFiles]
<hash>xxx.sys=xxx.sys
```

To make it clear, you have to add the text "<hash>" (sans quotes). That is not a placeholder for anything, but really the literal text. `makecat` will later replace it with the hash of the file in the .cat file.

To make it even clearer, "xxx" has to be be replaced with the proper names of your .cat file and driver, of course. :)

Comment: And what is `hash` in your change?

Comment: It is the plain text "<hash>" (sans quotes). It is not a placeholder for anthing, that was my misconception, too.