# Install libusb-win32 driver on Windows 8 without a digital certificate

Tags: windows-8, digital-signature, libusb-win32

I am trying to write an installer for an application that includes the installation of libusb-win32 on Windows 8.

I have encountered the fact that Windows 8 requires driver packages to have a CAT file but I don't have a digital Certificate.

The option to disable the digital signature checking on Windows 8 or using Zadig are not useful in my case.

So, is it possible to use libusb-win32 on Windows 8 without a digital certificate?

Comment: You can easily purchase a code signing certificate for signing a driver and a CAT file.

Comment: My question was about if it is possible to do it without purchasing a certificate

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Windows 8, will third-party INF driver files require a signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760513/in-windows-8-will-third-party-inf-driver-files-require-a-signature)

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Windows 8 drivers need to be signed - 
see duplicate post: [In Windows 8, will third-party INF driver files require a signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760513/in-windows-8-will-third-party-inf-driver-files-require-a-signature).

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/) to disable the driver signature enforcement. After disabling it, the un-signed libusb-win32 driver can be installed. I tried and it worked for me on a Windows 8.1 X64 box.